# How do I show multiple MKAnnotations with the callout?

Tags: iphone, ios4, mkmapview, mkannotation

I want to add multiple MKAnnotations with the callout showing.  I searched a few different threads on S.O and could not find a way to do it.  Has anyone figured out how to add multiple pins with the callout visible?

Comment: Do you mean with the callouts opened? All at the same time?

Comment: Yes, thats right.  I want to have all the callouts open.

Answer (score 0):

Ok!

You should use `[mapView selectAnnotation:currentAnnotation animated:FALSE]`

But be sure to place this in the  `- (void)mapViewDidFinishLoadingMap:(MKMapView *)mapView`
delegate method

[Trigger MKAnnotationView callout](http://www.iphonedevsdk.com/forum/iphone-sdk-development/19740-trigger-mkannotationview-callout-bubble.html#post110447)